# PagedList.MVC with EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing and other render option

Tags: model-view-controller, pagedlist

I've got pager like this:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.komentarzeListModeracja, page => 
    Url.Action("ModeracjaKomentarze", new { 
        DotyczyID = Model.DotyczyID, page 
        }), 
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { 
        HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "ModeracjaUpdate1" 
        }))
```

Could You tell me how can I add other render option to this ?. Is it possible ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already several versions\flavors incorporated into the class (intellisense enabled: Classic to OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime, Minimal and Bootstrap, etc.).

```
PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.TwitterBootstrapPagerAligned, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divpagedlist" }))

PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divpagedlist" }))
```

Simply, comma separated properties for the class.

A good reference at this time for PagedListRenderOptions (Class) properties:
http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PagedList.Mvc/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions
(please note this site is beta, cannot be sure how long link will be valid)

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("FileIndex",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }),
PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions()
{
    DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
    DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
    Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
    LiElementClasses = new List<string> { "myClass", "yourClass" },
    MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 10
}, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "fileListTable" }))
```